# Can't get stains off the ceiling

Tags: cleaning, stain

Moved into this place 2 years ago and these stains were on the ceiling. Ignored them but now it's time for moving and I don't trust the real estate agents as far as I can throw them.
I've had at it with some hot water and sugar soap and a sponge but they don't budge. Because it was there when we moved in I have no idea what the stains are/what they're caused by.
I was going to try jif and steam cleaner next to try shift them, but has anyone encountered ceiling stains like these? How do you get them off.
[image: stains on the ceiling]
[image: stains on the ceiling]
[image: stains on the ceiling]

Comment: This is mold. Luckily (?) for you, it was asked before, and got quite a few answers.

Comment: Why do you care about the real estate agents? Is this your property? Or will you need to pay for damages? The easiest thing would be to not be concerned. These kinds of repairs are the responsibility of the owner / landlord. They are included in the rent that you pay.